# Encrypting custom fields and returning unencrypted data on API calls

Tags: security, encryption

We have a need to encrypt a set of custom fields (data at rest) and we were thinking about using just the classic encryption. The data is served to mobile apps using API calls. Is it possible with just classic encryption to send the data in an unencrypted format when the mobile apps request it?

For e.g. I have a field SSN that (obviously) stores the social security number. Without encryption in place everything is good, the mobile app is able to display the logged on user's SSN. Since SSN is sensitive, there is a requirement to encrypt it even at rest. If we turn classic encryption on, will the API call to the mobile device be able to get the SSN as plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as the running user has the `View Encrypted Data` permission they should be able to see the clear text values retrieved through the API. According to the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) the only places classic encryption isn't supported are:

> Connect Offline, Salesforce for Outlook, lead conversion, workflow rule criteria or formulas, formula fields, outbound messages, default values, and Web-to-Lead and Web-to-Case forms